# How to style selected cell in QAbstractItemView?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I can' find any reference for QSS to style the QAbstractItemView table cells, I'm trying to change that dashed-lined rectangle on the second cell of the zoom column. This is the cell that is currently selected.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here [Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview).

I think I've used both:

`QTableView::item:focus`

`QTableView::item:selected`

to realize a similar design by changing the border and background colour and settings.